# Facebook Login with WebWorks

Tags: facebook, html, blackberry-webworks

I have been trying for some days now to login to facebook via a webworks application, I undesrtand that the FB.login can't work beacuse of a popup, and the oauth login has to go through a web server, I am currently trying to implement this plugin

https://github.com/rsweny/ChildBrowser-plugin-for-BlackBerry

but the readme file isn't really clear about how to implement, I understand that you need an ext directory in the app folder but not sure if I need to add something to the config.xml file or to any other.

Please help!

Thanks,

Jose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created some examples of how to integrate your app with Facebook, Twitter, and foursquare via OAuth.  They're targeted for BlackBerry 10, but should work on earlier versions as well.

Note:  I'll be updating them (for BlackBerry 10) to make use of the new ChildBrowser API.

OAuth Samples are available on GitHub @ https://github.com/ctetreault/BB10-WebWorks-Samples

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed! I am currently testing on Ripple and on a couple of blackberry simulators, in Ripple, when I click the button that has the call to the getAuthorization() method, it takes me to the facebook page and asks for permissions but when I click allow nothing happens, after refresh it won't go to the authorization page any more. I'm thinking that the redirect.php might be needing extra config or something? Now in the simulator I get a java error which states that my config.xml is missing an access for this link but I did set it, any ideas? Thanks!!